# Zero article usage

Tags: zero-article

Could anyone kindly comment on the usage of zero article in *...pen in hand* as it appears in the following context:

> Hunched over his desk, pen in hand, he was the spitting image of his father at work.
>
> [dictionary.com: spit and image](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spitting)

Comment: What would you like to know *specifically* about this zero-article example?

Comment: @BillJ The sentence is a quote from [Dictionay.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spitting): *spit and image* is and idiom too, albeit not as common as *spitting image*.

Answer (score 2):

Just an example that you can drop articles and possessives when they don't achieve much to get a shorter and more impressive phrase. Instead of "a pen in his hand" the author says "pen in hand" without any loss of clarity. I would say a literary device.